# JsonStore - Load single record with a restful url?

Tags: extjs, restful-url

All,

I have a JsonStore backing a form panel in my extjs app. I want to have the jsonStore load a single record based on an id value, but haven't found a good way to do that yet, and still keep the url restful.

My first attempt was to add a param to the jsonstore load() method with the id in it.  That only adds the id as a request param, not attached to the url:

```
http://my-app/users/?id=123
```

instead of what i want:

```
http://my-app/users/123
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually construct the URL that the store uses to query for data (via the implicit `HttpProxy` it creates for the URL).  So your loading function would look like:

```
function store_refresh() {
  json_store.proxy.conn.url = 'http://my-app/users/' + user_id;
  json_store.reload();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  One item: be sure to manually set the url back, otherwise other restful requests will send garbled urls to the server.